# How to use JSON array wrote on Android Studio while creating a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, android, json

I am making an app which gets the data from user (name, surname etc.) and keep the data in JSON file. What I have done are after getting data from user, insert them in a string array and convert string array to JSON array. Here is the code :

```
public void toJSON(){

  try {
    JSONArray List = new JSONArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      List.put(ad[j]);
      List.put(soyad[j]);
      List.put(sehir[j]);
      System.out.print(List.toString(1));
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

I have to create a JSON file but I do not know how to add datas to it after user enter the data.

Comment: yeahhhh...dont do that. use firebase or parse-server.... not a good idea to keep user data on their device. security 101.

Comment: But I must do it. I am working in a company and that is how they do.

Comment: you work for a company that takes user data and creates json files on local android devices? wow. .... just wow.

Comment: This a part of their job. I do not have to explain what they do or why I have to do it. I am here for ask help. Okey?

Comment: i dont need to know what your company does... i dont really care that much. but, you are also part of that company, so you should care enough to explain to them why this isnt a good idea... but, whatever, i gave you an example how to write jsonarrays in code....

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into other methods of persistence, such as Shared Preferences or Sql. That being said I'm not clear what your actual problem is or what you've tried to remedy it.

Comment: I wrote the code I shared above in Android Studio. Now I am trying to learn how I can use that JSON array in JSON file that I am trying to create, because there is no information in arrays yet(Users should enter the informations). You can think of it like you are going to create an e-mail address and it will be stored in JSON file in an array with other e-mail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you put data into a JSONArray.

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("query", "ran 3 miles");
        object.put("gender", "female");
        object.put("weight_kg", 72.5);
        object.put("height_cm", 167.64);
        object.put("age", 30);
        array.put(object);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will print

> [{"gender":"female","weight_kg":72.5,"height_cm":167.64,"query":"ran 3 miles","age":30}]

If you wish to use Lists<>... do this.

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("age", 5);
        object.put("name", "bill");
        list.add("string1");
        list.add("string2");
        object.put("strings", list);
        array.put(object);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will print the following:

> [{"strings":["string1","string2"],"name":"bill","age":5}]

Taking what you just learned, lets go deeper.

Lets say you have a name and email edittext, like so.

```
EditText name = findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText email = findViewById(R.id.email);
```

You have an onclick listener, maybe a "save" button. When you tape that, you need to get the information from those edit texts.

```
... // clicked save
String nameString = name.getText().toString().trim();
String emailString = email.getText().toString().trim();
// Create your json file.

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    String nameString = "john"; // dont need this, this is from the edit text (example)
    String emailString = "email@email.com"; // dont need this, this is from the edit text (example)
    try {
        object.put("name", nameString);
        object.put("email", emailString);
        array.put(object);
        System.out.println(array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This will print out...

> [{"name":"john","email":"email@email.com"}]

Convert a String List to a JSONArray:

Helper method:

```
public static JSONArray convertToJSON (List<String> list) {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put(list);
    return array;
}
```

Code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("string1");
    list.add("string2");
    list.add("string3");
    list.add("string4");
    list.add("string5");
    list.add("string6");
    list.add("string7");
    list.add("string8");

    System.out.println(convertToJSON(list));
```

Result

> [["string1","string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7","string8"]]

Comment: Thank you very much but this is not the answer of my question

Comment: @Pelin :: If this did not answer your question, then your question was not well define. DroiDev gave you an excellent example on how to create a JSON structure. What else do you need? How to store the data to device storage? How to open a JSON file from the device and add more data to it? Be more specific what is missing in this answer.

Comment: @Barns :: You may be right, my question may not be clear. "I wrote the code I shared above in Android Studio. Now I am trying to learn how I can use that JSON array in JSON file that I am trying to create, because there is no information in arrays yet(Users should enter the informations). You can think of it like you are going to create an e-mail address and it will be stored in JSON file in an array with other e-mail addresses."

Comment: @DroiDev I think I still cannot explain my question well. Again I thank you so much for your attention but I am going to google it.

Comment: a user types in their email...they click save. you take the email, and append it to a json file. yes? ... if so... what part of that are you having an issue with? because the code you posted above wasnt even how you create a json array. it wasnt even close.

Comment: @DroiDev Oh I have realized the other half of the code you wrote.... This is completely my mistake. I apolagize. This is very helpful. Thank you again and again..

Comment: @Pelin good luck in your coding journey. upvote/approve if this solved an issue. :)